# Apply addclass method to execcommand

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight, execcommand

Text highlight using `window.getSelection()` working fine. But when I want to highlight preselected saved text not working. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
var highlight = 'Hello There';
document.execCommand('formatblock', false, 'p')
var listId = highlight.focusNode.parentNode; // window.getSelection() not used
$(listId).addClass("customClass");
```

Comment: `highlight` is a _string_. `getSelection` doesn't return a string. It returns a [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to highlight the content of the DOM node containing the searched text, you should use jQuery's `:contains` selector:

```
$('span:contains(Hello There)').addClass("customClass");
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/wifulereyi/2/

If you want to highlight only the searched text, you need to process the jQuery selection result first, and then use something like `.wrapInner('<span class="highlight"></span>')`. In such case, you might better off use a plugin like [jQuery.highlight](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html)